# How to watch python script which runs in background?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Im running python script in background on ubuntu linux with this command:

```
python script.py &
```

When Im closing terminal, its run on background

But how I can watch what script.py output, when opening terminal again?

Comment: are you sure it runs in the background if you close the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many options for monitor the script in background.

1. First, run Screen command if you would like to disconnect the terminal. If you disconnect your terminal your script process will be an exit.

```
$ screen

$ python  script.py &

Disconnect your terminal

$ screen -ls 

Copy the PID and run the below command

$ screen -r PID
```

You are able to see your script output.

Answer (score 1):

Several Options:

1. Use a tool like [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/%22tmux%22)
2. Use `tail -f` on the log file
3. Direct stdout to a file and use `tail -f` on it

`python script.py > /tmp/logfile &`

then later:

```
tail -f /tmp/logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) to run your python script